# Populate cell with value from drop down list or table excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I can populate a certain cell using this formula;

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(Create!$C3,tbl_attributes,9,FALSE)),"", (VLOOKUP(Create!$C3,tbl_attributes,9,FALSE)))
```

This formula looks at the 9 column in a table and populates the cell with a predefined value from a table.

but say i choose an item from a dropdown list i want that value to  populate the cell that has just been populated from using the formula above if that cell only contains a `0` or is `blank`.

I can do this by using;

```
=Create!G2 <---- Value selected in dropdown list
```

How can i combine the two formulas.

Thanks,

EDIT 1:
Getting a `too many arguments error`  ?

```
=IF(OR(IFERROR((VLOOKUP(Create!$C3,tbl_attributes,9,FALSE)),"", (VLOOKUP(Create!$C3,tbl_attributes,9,FALSE)))=0, IFERROR((VLOOKUP(Create!$C3,tbl_attributes,9,FALSE)),"", (VLOOKUP(Create!$C3,tbl_attributes,9,FALSE)))="", ISBLANK(IFERROR((VLOOKUP(Create!$C3,tbl_attributes,9,FALSE)),"", (VLOOKUP(Create!$C3,tbl_attributes,9,FALSE))))), Create!E2, VLOOKUP(Create!$C3,tbl_attributes,9,FALSE))
```

Comment: I don't understand the second part of your question. How are you wanting to use the value you choose from the drop-down list? Also, your current formula can be condensed as `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(Create!$C3,tbl_attributes,9,FALSE),"")` if you're running a later version of Excel.

Comment: @TotsieMae, I would like to populate a separate cell with the value selected in the drop-down list. But if that cell already contains certain data other then zero do not change it. Also many thanks for that Tip.

Comment: What is 'Create!G2'? Is this some kind of formula to do what?

Comment: @BharatAnand It should be from  worksheet **Create** Cell **G2**, but I dont understand what the OP trys to achieve

Comment: @BharatAnand,I have updated my question to try and make it clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, `IF` your current code (either the full version you posted, or the condensed `IFERROR` version that TotsieMae provided in comments) is 0 `OR` blank, then you want to show value `Create!G2`?  Remember, however that there is a difference between `=""` and an actual Blank cell.

The abbreviated code below considers a lookup result of 0, Blank or "" (including error) to be reasons to return `Create!G2`.  You don't need to look for errors on that last VLOOKUP, because an error would already have returned `Create!G2` instead.

`=IF(OR(IFERROR(..)=0, IFERROR(..)="", ISBLANK(IFERROR(..))), Create!G2, VLOOKUP(..))`

Comment: Thanks for providing a possible solution . i have tried your formula and im getting `You've entered int too many arguments for this function`.

Comment: You've put 3 arguments in each `IFERROR(..)` - it only needs the first 2.  You wrote it like an `IF(ISERROR(..), ..)`